# Why erasing element from vector while iterating causes Segmentation fault (core dumped)?

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault, iteration, erase

The following generates the problem I am having in a larger scale program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> vec{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    for (unsigned i = vec.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (vec[i] > 2) vec.erase(vec.begin() + i);
        else cout << vec[i] << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

This causes `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

After a bit debugging, I found that changing the code the following way, "solves" the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> vec{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    for (unsigned i = vec.size() - 1; i >= 1; --i) {
        if (vec[i] > 2) vec.erase(vec.begin() + i);
        else cout << vec[i] << "  ";
    }
    if (vec[0] > 2) vec.erase(vec.begin());
    else cout << vec[0] << "  ";
    cout << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

This is printing what I expected to get.

```
2 1
```

Is not it what the for loop was doing in the first program? I just moved the condition for the beginning of the vector outside the loop!

Also what is the proper way to erase element from vector while iterating like so?

Comment: `i` is unsigned, therefore `i >= 0;` is **always** true. Therefore that loop never ends, and eventually `i` underflows (which means it will wrap to UINT_MAX and continue marching on into oblivion whence you use it as an index to a vector clearly not so gregarious).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment says, `i` is `unsigned`, therefore `i >= 0` is always true. When `i` becomes less than `0` it actually becomes a large positive number, and then indexing into the vector with `i` invokes undefined behavior.

The *proper* way to erase elements from a vector is to use the [erase-remove-if](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) idiom:

```
vec.erase(std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](int i) {
            return i > 2; }), vec.end());
```